# Print a corresponding string of numbers of relationship between two DNA string in Java

Tags: java, string

I have the following two DNA strings "AACAGTTACC" and "TA-AGGT-CA", I would like to print a corresponding string of numbers, where two elements of two strings indicate a match (0), two elements indicate a mismatch (1) and one element indicates a gap (2).

For example the above two string would produce “10220010201”

I tried a loop through one of the string and check if string.charAt(i).contains("-") but it does not work.

```
String numbers = "";
for(int k = 0; k<adnX.length();k++) {
    // I would like to append numbers to the numbers string
    StdOut.printf("%s %s\n", adnX.charAt(k),adnY.charAt(k));
}
```

Comment: Can you also paste your code?

Comment: It's about genes... We don't have to understand what would be the "match". Is it TA, TG... You know what I mean.

Comment: A match is when an element of the first string is equal to an element of the second string

Comment: I got you, **but** show us the desired output from your example. `AACAGTTACC` is the first String and `TA-AGGT-CA` is the second one. What would be result in this case?

Comment: How does `"AACAGTTACC"` and `"TA-AGGT-CA"` produce `"10220010201"`? Particularly the 4th position result of `"2"`? There's no "gap" at the 4th position in either input string.

Comment: `string.charAt(i).contains("-")` won't compile (because `charAt()` returns a `char`). `string.charAt(i) == '-'` is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Two methods are presented here:

- the main method and an auxiliary method.
- The auxiliary checks if a given character is a valid DNA character.

The main method has two main parts.

Firstly, it initialises `s1` and `s2` with the required DNA strings and creates `s3` which is an empty string. `s3` will be used to store the corresponding numbers in case of a match, miss-match or gap. It assumes that both `s1` and `s2` have the same length.

In the first part it checks if the character at `i`-th position in `s1` and `s2` is a valid DNA character, if it's not it appends a `2` to `s3`.

In the second part (i.e., of the `if` statement, the `else`), it checks if the character at `i`-th position in `s1` is the same as character at `i`-th position in `s2`. If it is then it appends a `0`, otherwise it appends a `1`.

The result is printed at the end.

```
public class DNACheck {

    public static boolean isDNA(char c) {
        String dna = "ATGC";
        boolean inSequence = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < dna.length() && !inSequence;i++) {
            if (dna.charAt(i) == c) inSequence = true;
        }
        return inSequence;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "AACAGTTACC";
        String s2 = "TA-AGGT-CA";

        String s3 = "";

        for(int k = 0;k< s1.length();k++) {
           // I would like to append numbers to the numbers string
           if (!isDNA(s1.charAt(k)) || !isDNA(s2.charAt(k))) {
               s3 = s3 + '2';
           }
           else {
               if (s1.charAt(k) == s2.charAt(k)) {
                   s3 = s3 + '0';
               }
               else {
                   s3 = s3 + '1';
               }
           } 
        }

        System.out.println(s3);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that inputs always have the same length and two gaps should result in a match:

```
String adnX = "AACAGTTACC";
String adnY = "TA-AGGT-CA";
StringBuilder numbers = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < adnX.length(); i++) {
  if (adnX.charAt(i) == adnY.charAt(i)) {
    numbers.append(0);
  } else if (adnX.charAt(i) == '-' || adnY.charAt(i) == '-') {
    numbers.append(2);
  } else {
    numbers.append(1);
  }
}

System.out.println(adnX);
System.out.println(adnY);
System.out.println(numbers);
```

Will output:

```
AACAGTTACC
TA-AGGT-CA
1020010201
```

Comment: I tried this and I gave an error of “Incompatible operand types char and String”

Comment: It compiles and runs on OpenJDK 9.0.4, either you have a quite outdated JDK or you must have pasted something wrong. Which line is the problem for you? Could it be that you double quoted `'-'` instead of single quotes I used in `else if`?

Comment: Oh I changed it to single quote and it worked but I don’t understand the reason

Comment: Single quote is a `char` literal. Double quote is a `String` literal. Two different types just like `1` is `int` and `1f` is `float`.

Comment: This code works fine. And, you should accept it as an answer (mostly b/c I didn't even understood the question properly)!